# Running examples in Openaerostruct which uses Openmdao

Tags: openmdao

### I have run the basic examples given in Openmdao and Openaerostruct including the walk-throughs. However, one of the examples "run_aerostruct_uCRM.multipoint .py is throwing an error:

File "C:\Users\Narahari\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "D:/D_volume_ADE/Aircraft_Design_course/MDO_Aerospace/OpenAeroStruct-master/openaerostruct/examples/run_aerostruct_uCRM_multipoint.py", line 28, in 
    from openmdao.api import IndepVarComp, Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver, pyOptSparseDriver, SqliteRecorder, ExecComp, SqliteRecorder

ImportError: cannot import name 'pyOptSparseDriver' from 'openmdao.api' (C:\Users\Narahari\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\api.py)

Not sure what is going wrong, any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance 
Narahari

Answer (score 0):

it looks like example requires pyoptsparse to run. You need to [install pyoptsparse from here](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/pyoptsparse). However, the latest master branch of [OpenAeroStruct](https://github.com/mdolab/openaerostruct) has updated this example to not require that driver, using the scipy driver instead. So if you pull down the commit [#8cee773](https://github.com/mdolab/OpenAeroStruct/commit/8cee77346e1d6ba3b5d1cba93a60fe2776a2dfb3) or newer you should be able to run it.